# May I use "when" with a time expression like "10 minutes back"?

Tags: word-usage, time

> 10 minutes back when I checked the score, X team was losing.

Is this expression correct? Use of the word 'when' sounds odd to me. What would the right construct be?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is perfectly fine, although perhaps *ago* sounds better than *back*. It’s just like this:

- When I looked outside ten minutes ago, it was still snowing heavily.
- It was still snowing heavily when I looked outside ten minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. The phrase with *when* is a distinct modifier and can be moved or omitted; and when you write it, it might be set off with a pair of commas :

> 10 minutes back, X was losing.
>   When I checked the score, X was losing.
>   10 minutes back, when I checked the score, X was losing.

As tchrist tells you, *ago* may be substituted for *back*; but this is true only if your 'reference time', the time to which you are relating the event, is the present moment when you are speaking. If you are relating the event to other events in the past you cannot use *ago* but must use *before that* or *back*:

> **Right now** X **is** winning; but 10 minutes **ago** when I checked the score, X was losing.
>   **At half time** X **was** winning; but 10 minutes **back**, when I checked the score, X **was** [or, *had been*] losing.

Note that this use is different from *back when*, an intensive variant of *when* which locates the event you are speaking of in an explicitly remote past:

> *Back when* I was a boy, Alabama schools were still segregated.

All of these uses of *back* are colloquial rather than formal.

Answer (score 1):

OP's usage is "correct", in that I doubt anyone can cite a "grammatical rule" forbidding it, [but](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minutes%20ago%20when,minutes%20back%20when&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

...I'd advise against it, purely on the ground virtually no-one else uses the form.

As StoneyB points out, "ago" is only valid when the "reference time" is the *current time of speaking*, whereas "back" can in principle also be used of a reference time in the past...

> This afternoon he scored a brilliant goal! He'd been on the substitute bench only 5 minutes back.

But I don't like that one little bit. I'd recommend using **ago** whenever the referrence time is the present, and **earlier, before, prior to that,** or **previously**, for example, if the timeframe is entirely in the past.

Comment: really nice note about the "difference" between ago and back. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *when* is perfectly fine in that sentence.
You are saying that, in the moment you checked the score, it was unfavorable for that team. Five minutes earlier, the score could have been different, but you don't know it; the score could have changed five minutes after you checked, but you don't know it.

I would rather rephrase the sentence as:

> 10 minutes ago, when I checked the score, X team was losing.

> When I checked the score, 10 minutes ago, X team was losing.